# C# List - remove list from another list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, replace

Say I have a list of strings

```
1,2,3,a,b,a,b,c,1,2
```

I have a second list of strings

```
a,b,c
```

I want to remove the second list from the first resulting in

```
1,2,3,a,b,1,2
```

What's the best way to do this with with two `List<string>`?

Most methods/questions/answers I see involve lists revolve around individual lines of second list being removed from the first (all a's... all b's... all c's...).

I don't want that... I only want to remove those where the a followed by b followed by c.

Edit:

Couple caveats: The Second List is generally two or three strings and CAN appear multiple times (Say, instead, the second list is `1,2`. It's contained in the first list twice).

Comment: This will take real coding. What code do you have so far?

Comment: Can you solve an easier problem? can you write a method that returns true if the second list is contained in the first?

Comment: @TrevorAsh I've been trying some loops over loops, but I haven't had anything I'd consider successful. The biggest problem for me has been that the second list is variable length (normally 2 or 3 strings in Second List to remove from First). I was hoping I was missing something stupidly "easy" (like the join/replace/split answer, which might work for my purposes).

Comment: @EricLippert That's a good idea as well... create a method to return the indexes where the sublists occur... then remove from those points.

Comment: Your question is arguably a set of requirements. Any code to show?  [ask]

Comment: @WernerCD I provided an answer below without weird tricks that removed multiple matches (the function cant't be recursive because if you had "1,2,a,a,b,c,b,c" the second iteration would falsely find a second a,b,c. But if that's the behavior you want, just refactor Backs solution to be recursive. The problem with string.Join is if your string happens to contain the character joined with.

Comment: @MickyD I felt like my question was "Borderline" but I had a minor case of "Writers Block". At the core, this question was "simple" but none of the related/similar questions really had what I needed. Most "List removed from List" questions are remove individual items and I was looking for the entire list in sequence. Maybe not the perfect question, but the code I had was missing important parts that a few of the answers got spot on.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<string>(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "1", "2" });
var sublist = new List<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c" });

var start = -1;
var index = 0;

while (index < list.Count - sublist.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sublist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i + index] == sublist[i] && i == 0)
        {
            start = i + index;
        }
        else if (list[i + index] != sublist[i])
        {
            start = -1;
            index++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (start != -1)
    {
        list.RemoveRange(start, sublist.Count);
        index -= sublist.Count;
    }
}

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.Write(item + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With hack:

```
var list = new List<string>(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "1", "2" });
var sublist = new List<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c" });

var a = string.Join("#", list);
var b = string.Join("#", sublist);

var result =
    new List<string>(a.Replace(b, string.Empty).Split(new[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.Write(item + ",");
}
```

This solution has very bad perfomance, but it can work for small lists.

Comment: @un-lucky it prints 1, 2, 3, a, b,a, 1, 2. what is wrong?

Comment: Hadn't thought about join/replace/split... it might work for what I'm trying to do - although I'd not mind something a bit more performant. I could wrap this up into an extension method to hide the ugly (and eventually replace with something better), but it could be a good "simple" option.

Comment: @WernerCD look at my other answer - it's much better in perfomance

Comment: @WernerCD : much better

Comment: Both answers are spot on... Give me a couple minutes to wrap my head around the other answer (and fit it into my current problem) and I think it's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

With this few lines you could achieve the same. First convert it to String and then replace with 2nd string and convert it back to char array.

```
        List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "1", "2" };
        List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

        string strA = string.Join("", listA);
        string strB = string.Join("", listB);

        strA = strA.Replace(strB, string.Empty);
        List<string> resultList = strA.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Below code if you need to support full fledged strings

```
        List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "abc1", "2abc2", "3", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "1", "2" };
        List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

        string strA = string.Join(",", listA);
        string strB = string.Join(",", listB) ;

        strA = strA.Replace(strB, string.Empty).Replace(",,", ",");
        List<string> resultList = strA.Split(',').ToList();
```

Comment: list of strings, not chars

Comment: try this input `List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "abc1", "2abc2", "3", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "1", "2" };`

Comment: If we need to support strings like that, i have added another code , please see that

Answer (score 1):

Removes multiple matches if this is what you expect. I'm not thrilled with the implementation, but it appears to work. I used a Stack (last in first out) because I'm lazy.

```
  List<string> target = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "a", "b", "c", "1" };
  List<string> match = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

  Stack<int> matchIndexes = new Stack<int>();

  for (int x = 0; x < target.Count - match.Count; x++)
  {
      int matches = 0;
      for (int y = 0; y < match.Count; y++)
      {
          if (target[x + y] != match[y])
          {
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              matches++;
          }
      }

      if (matches == match.Count)
      {
          matchIndexes.Push(x);
      }
  }

  while(matchIndexes.Count > 0)
  {
      int index = matchIndexes.Pop();
      target.RemoveRange(index, match.Count);
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just iterate through each item in list 2, and remove it from list 1.

```
foreach(string listItem in list2)
{
    list1.Remove(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Yes, and it removes the first instance of each of the characters in the second list. Is that not what was asked?

Comment: this is wrong, you need to remove whole sequence, not individual elements